# xamarin UIButton event async issue - waitingforactivation

Tags: c#, ios, uibutton, async-await

I was working through some video tutorials about iphone app development using xamarin and I seem to have run into an async issue.

I have a button that when clicked runs an async method which makes a http request. However, when clicked the async method never runs, and when I check the status it says "waitingforactivation"

```
public class RootViewModel : UIViewController
{
    private UIButton _button;
    private string response;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        Title = "Load Async";
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray;

        _button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        _button.Frame = new RectangleF(0, View.Bounds.Height - 60, View.Bounds.Width, 60);
        _button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 0, 0);
        _button.SetTitle("Get Async", UIControlState.Normal);
        _button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255), UIControlState.Normal);

        response = string.Empty;

        _button.TouchUpInside += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            response = await DoStuffAsync();
            Title = response;
        };

        View.AddSubview(_button);
    }

    private async Task<string> DoStuffAsync()
    {
        var url = @"http://www.google.co.uk";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            return response.Substring(0, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help as to why this fails would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `TouchUpInside` invoke at all?

Comment: Hi Yuval, yes it does invoke, but it doesn't fulfil the request

Comment: Do all other execution lines occur other than your `async` method?